# How to add new connection provider to Visual Studio?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, ms-access, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 for development in business intelligence (BI). In  window **Connection Manager**, there're 9 native providers :

- Microsoft Jet 4.0 OLE DB Provider
- Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Analysis Services 11.0
- Micorsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle
- ...

The provider needed is ***Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine OLE DB Provider*** (Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0), which is not included in this list. However, this provider does exist in my computer : I've used in Excel 2016, as a Microsoft Access connection provider.

So how can I "link" / "add" this provider to VS2010 and make it recognized ?

Comment: You tag it as VS 2012 but mention VS 2010 in your question...which is it?

Comment: This is a spelling mistake, sorry about it. It is VS 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely happening because you may have installed the **64-bit version** of [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255).

**Visual Studio / BIDS is a 32-bit application**, and hence cannot "see" any of the **64-bit providers**, including the **Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine OLE DB Provider** that you installed.

To fix this,

1. Uninstall the **64-bit redistributable** that you previously installed.
2. Download and install the **32-bit redistributable** [from here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255). Note the link shows both 32-bit and 64-bit versions, make sure you select the 1st one (marked below)
   [image]
3. Now you should be able to see your list of available connection managers.

Comment: Excellent answer, simple and explicit. Thanks, Shiva.

Answer (score 1):

Just for informational purposes...You see the provider via Excel because it is installed within the context of Office Suite of products. It is not a provider that is available system wide or where VS and SQL Server could utilize it; to get this you have to install the distribution [pointed out by @Shiva](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36725024/847990).

An Example:
[image]

[Learn more about 32 versus 64 bit history](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2015/02/is-my-ssis-package-running-in-32-or-64.html).

Comment: Thanks for your additional explanation, Shawn. It's very helpful.